# Javascript regex to reject non ASCII-US characters

Tags: javascript, regex

```
^[^\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]+$
```

This regex will properly **fail** to match a string that contains *non-printing* (hex 00-1f) or *ASCII extended* characters (hex 80-FF), but, unlike PHP, lets non-ASCII utf-8 characters  pass. (eg. 日本واستقرارهहिन्दीދިވެހިބަސްગુજરાતી한)

Looking at the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) on UTF-8 all of those should fall in the 80-ff range. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Also, if you could explain how to ignore quoted text, you would be my hero forever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm... instead of rejecting byte ranges, try matching actual Unicode characters, e.g.:

```
^[\u0020-\u007e]+$
```