# Java Script regular expression for detecting non-ascii characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How can we use java script to restrict the use of non-ascii characters in a specific text field..? thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you want them removed or replaced?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465874/javascript-regex-to-reject-non-ascii-us-characters (I'm out of votes)

Comment: @jnpcl Just an alert to the user will do...... removing them is also a good option

Comment: There are some jQuery Plugins that will do this. Some are [simple](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/aphanumeric), others are [robust](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate).

Comment: can you give me some "javascript" code..? i don't know how to use regular expressions in java script

Comment: @sasidhar - `can you give me some "javascript" code..? ` Why dosen't your company hire programmers?

Comment: @sln i am sorry, but i am student trying to learn... you could be more helpful than that i guess.

Comment: **str.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, '');** (Reference: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-string-exercise-32.php)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ascii is defined as the characters in the range of 000-177 (octal), therefore

```js
function containsAllAscii(str) {
    return  /^[\000-\177]*$/.test(str) ;
}

console.log ( containsAllAscii('Hello123-1`11'));
console.log ( containsAllAscii('ábcdé'));
```

You probably don't want to accept non-printing characters `\000-\037`, maybe your regex should be `/\040-\176/`

Answer (score 1):

I came accross this page trying to look for a function to sanitize a string to be used as friendly URL in a CMS system. The CMS is multilingual but I wanted to prevent non-ascii characters to appear in the URL. So instead of using ranges, I simply used (based on the solution above):

```
function verify_url(txt){
    var str=txt.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,""); // remove spaces
    if (str == '') {
        alert("Please enter a URL for this page.");
        document.Form1.url.focus();
        return false;
    }
    found=/^[a-zA-Z0-9._\-]*$/.test(str); // we check for specific characters. If any character does not match these allowed characters, the expression evaluates to false
    if(!found) {
        alert("The can only contain letters a thru z, A thru Z, 0 to 9, the dot, the dash and the underscore. No spaces, German specific characters or Chinese characters are allowed. Please remove all punctuation (except for the dot, if you use it), and convert all non complying characters. In German, you may convert umlaut 'o' to 'oe', or in Chinese, you may use the 'pinyin' version of the Chinese characters.");
        document.Form1.url.focus();
    }
    return found;
}
```