# How to detect Chinese input before submit a form?

Tags: jquery, web

Just like the title, how to detect the users' input whether he enters Chinese or not?

I am wondering if jQuery can make it or not? because I don't wanna after submit the form to avoid a lot of server workload.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to only allow ASCII characters using a regular expression, as in [this example someone posted for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5185722/63717). That has the advantage that it would also exclude other non-ASCII characters such as Cyrillic.