# Remove strange symbol with jquery/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using a proxy to get google results. Which I then show as plain html. The problem is that I get a strange symbol every now and than that looks like this �

I know it might have something to do with my proxy.php and language/character settings. But since I don't know PHP I was wondering wether I could remove this symbol using jquery/javascript. I tried `display:none` and `&('�').remove();` with no luck.

ps I dont know if you see the same symbol as I am seeing in my browser, but in case you dont: its a '?' inside a little black square.

Comment: The symbol is probably not �, but rather a unicode symbol which cannot be displayed. When rendering the text, the browser uses the [replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character). On removing non-latin characters see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185326/java-script-regular-expression-for-detecting-non-ascii-characters.

Comment: Like @onon15 said, this really sounds like an encoding issue, try to set it to utf-8

Comment: I tried this in the php file `header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');` No luck..

Comment: I want to answer my own question but when I click the button it doesn't do anything so Im just posting it like this. I put in my php file this: `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
ob_start('mb_output_handler');`  It seems to work:) Question solved

Comment: If you make the browser output in utf8 that is just one step, you also need your text (for instance from the database) to be in utf8. This function can help with that http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should force the `charset` header of your response to be `UTF-8` (or other suitable charset for your needs), or you could previously convert all your unicode characters on server side with [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

example (taken from manual page)

```
<?php
$text = "A strange string to pass, maybe with some ø, æ, å characters.";

foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){
    echo mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', $chr)." : ".$chr."<br>";   
}
?>
```

Comment: I already anwserred my question..:) But Im accepting this anwser it might work for someone else