# regular expression to match basic ascii characters

Tags: javascript

I am checking for the regular expression which matches only basic ASCII characters in javascript. 
I tried the below solutions given in the other threads in the forum.

```
^[\\u0000-\\u007F]*$
^[\x00-\x7F]*$
```

However, the above is not working as supposed to be when i gave the English alphabet also. Any suggestions to come up with the regular expression for accepting the basic ASCII characters please ?

Edit: I am trying to validate a text box description field.

Comment: Can you show some code reproducing the problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185326/java-script-regular-expression-for-detecting-non-ascii-characters

Comment: @PartiallyFinite, Thanks. 
    /^[\000-\177]*$/ seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be be working fine.

For a string (containing unicode):

```
"sdfs \u2022"                                 // "sdfs •"
```

For matching only ASCII part of the string:

```
"sdfs \u2022".match("[\\u0000-\\u007F]*")     // "sdfs "
```

But if you need to check that the string is composed of only ASCII:

```
"sdfs \u2022".match("^[\\u0000-\\u007F]*$")   // null
```

For a string (not containing unicode):

```
"sdfs ".match("^[\\u0000-\\u007F]*$")         // "sdfs "
```