# Warn on non-ASCII Characters in Django Form

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-forms

I'm trying to add some client-side Ajax validation of my Django form. I want to warn users, as they are typing in a field, if any of the characters they just inputted are not ascii.

I originally put the basic python to check for ascii characters in my form's `clean` method. I don't want to do that, though, as I don't want to produce an error but rather just give a warning message and let the user continue with the rest of the form.

```
try:
    field_value.decode('ascii')
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    #raise forms.ValidationError("Non-ASCII characters may cause issues in registering your data. Consider removing these characters. You may still submit at your own risk.")
    # Just want to show a warning so the user can still submit the form if they wish
```

I want to show a small warning under the field as the user is typing. I've tried using django-dajax, but am not sure. How can I do this?

EDIT: 
To clarify, I want to show the warning before the user submits the form. So, as they are filling out the form...

Comment: just want to say _"Non-ASCII characters may cause issues in registering your data. Consider removing these characters. You may still submit at your own risk."_ is a bad message to show to the user. Firstly, as the website builder it should be _your_ responsibility to fix the issues with submitting non-ascii chars. Secondly a user is not likely to even know what 'Non-ASCII' chars are, and they won't know what the 'risk' is and whether they should take it. If you can't fix your backend code to accept all chars, at least identify exactly which chars cause problem...

Comment: ...and then don't allow them to submit any data which you know will fail.

Comment: thank you for your response @Anentropic but this is for a scientific community that knows ascii is. Additionally, the issue with non-ascii chars is not on my end but with an external party to which the registered data is sent. This is how we need the system to work. I just need help figuring out the js/ajax validation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript to validate that form field.

Example (using jQuery):

```js
<form>
    <input name="whatever" id="fieldId">
    ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    /* Define a function to check the form field value */

    function containsAllAscii(str) {
        return  /^[\000-\177]*$/.test(str); // returns true if all are ASCII characters. false otherwise. 
    }

    /* Now a little jQuery */

    $('#fieldId').on('change', function() {
        str = $(this).val();
        is_valid = containsAllAscii(str);

        if (!is_valid) {
            window.alert("There are Non-ASCII characters in the input field");
        }
    });   
</script>
```

The above code will check the given field's value whenever it changes (*i.e.* loses focus). You can use `.on('keyup', ...` instead of `.on('change', ...` which will check the field's value as the user is typing.

Finally, the error message that is shown is just a browser alert. Which is crappy. You can display a beautiful error message, you just need to learn a little more of jQuery. But I hope I've given you a good starting point.

---

Credits:

The code for `containsAllAscii` function is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5185722/1925257) by [Juan Mendes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227299/juan-mendes).

Comment: I gave up on trying to get a nice error message for now, and just finished implementing something very similar to your answer! Thank you! At least I can get the message across now.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
> <input type="text" pattern="^[\x20-\x7F]+$" id ....>
```

in html

Answer (score 0):

In your django form, create a custom field and take advantage of the media class.

```
from django import forms

class MyWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('pretty.css',)
        }
        js = ('animations.js', 'actions.js')
```

and set the js to the javascript file you will use for validation. something along the lines of the the other answer

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/media/