# Cleaning the json string from special chars

Tags: javascript, regex

Im using an API to receive data, several parts cause problem which I need to resolve:

```
"Apple® iPad® 2 with Wi-Fi - 16GB"

"Rocketfish™ - Premium Vehicle Charger for Apple® iPad™, iPhone® and iPod®"
```

I need to remove special UTF8 chars such as `® ™`, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Are you sure that you can't work with those characters? Anyway, what you're looking for isn't a regex but a simple char by char filter. Way faster and way more efficient.

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465874/javascript-regex-to-reject-non-ascii-us-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please make sure you absolutely cannot work with those "problematic" symbols. Clean modern program should correctly understand input in any language.

As for your request to remove anything unreadable, it is better to specify what you want to leave instead, since F. Calderan's example won't remove any extra Unicode symbols above specified FFFF position. So, considering you only want ASCII:

```
str = str.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007F]+/g, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remove all symbols except basic latin just apply a regular expression like

```
str = str.replace(/[\u0080-\uFFFF]+/g, "");
```

See [this list of unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) to choose which characters you need to accept or not

Comment: Regexes are useless here. It's better to just look for every character and check if it's an ascii one or skip it.

Comment: You probably don't want the beginning and end of string anchors in there. Your RegExp will only match strings composed entirely of the characters you are tying to remove

Comment: @F.Calderan - Oh yes that too, but you still need to lose the ^ and $

Comment: Still not removing: "Apple® - iPad® 2 with Wi-Fi - 16GB - Black".replace(/^[\u0080-\uFFFF]+$/g, "");

Comment: Why? You need to travel entire string and regexp engine should do that faster than manual traversal and reassembling/splicing a new string by hand.

Comment: Nevermind, I did some tests, and javascript is just awfully slow when it comes to concatenation of characters.